# Is CONSTANT.equals(VARIABLE) faster than VARIABLE.equals(CONSTANT)?

Tags: java

I had an interesting conversation with one of my team mate.

Is `CONSTANT.equals(VARIABLE)` faster than `VARIABLE.equals(CONSTANT)`in Java?

I suspect this to be a false statement. But I am trying to figure out what should be qualitative reasoning behind this?

I know in both the cases the performance will not differ to any kind of significant state. But it was a recommendation under BEST PRACTICES which is making me uncomfortable. That's the reason I am looking towards a good reasoning that I want to present with this case.

Please HELP

Comment: possible duplicate of [Interview : Java Equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712100/interview-java-equals)

Comment: I have a more important question: is there any situations where a (hypothetical) difference would actually matter?

Comment: @JigarJoshi: this question is specifically about speed, the linked-to one is not.

Comment: There is no performance difference, but there is  difference, please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712100/interview-java-equals

Comment: @Joachim Agree, I should have marked it related, can't revert it now

Comment: I am not saying if this will affect progress or not but, Adding this to be part of BEST PRACTICES is what making me uncomfortable.

Comment: @Jochim: Agree with you, but adding any false or imaginative Practices in Best Practice making me uncomfortable, that's the reason I turned up to this forum

Comment: @AshishAgarwal: I agree. If it comes to best practices, then the question of different behaviour is **much** more important (one of those is "save" against `null` values in the variable, the other is not).

Comment: @Ashish please read 5th comment:)

Comment: Ohh, My fault, So deleted the comment. Thanks

Comment: Constant equal should always come first before string

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Interesting question. Here is the test I wrote:

```
public class EqualsTest {
    public static String CONST = "const";
    public void constEqVar(String var) {
        CONST.equals(var);
    }
    public void varEqConst(String var) {
        var.equals(CONST);
    }
}
```

Then I compiled it using javac: `javac EqualsTest.java` and disassembled it using `javap`: `javap -c EqualsTest`.

Here is the relevant snippet of javap output:

```
public void constEqVar(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   getstatic       #2; //Field CONST:Ljava/lang/String;
   3:   aload_1
   4:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
   7:   pop
   8:   return

public void varEqConst(java.lang.String);
  Code:
   0:   aload_1
   1:   getstatic       #2; //Field CONST:Ljava/lang/String;
   4:   invokevirtual   #3; //Method java/lang/String.equals:(Ljava/lang/Object;)Z
   7:   pop
   8:   return
```

As you can see the only difference between theses 2 methods is order of operations: getstatic and then aload_1 in first case and aload_1 + getstatic in second case.

Pretty obvious that the execution time should not depend on this order.

The only reason to prefer `const.equals(var)` rather than `var.equals(const)` is to avoid `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 26):

For me its not a speed issue, its a relability issue.

e.g.

```
"Hello".equals(a); // will never throw a NPE
a.equals("Hello"); // can throw an NPE.
```

You may prefer it to blow up when a is `null` but usually I don't.

Answer (score 2):

That depends only on the implementation of the equals method. It could be quicker, it could be the slower and it could be the same... Often it is the same. Also it does not depend on the fact that one is a variable and the other a constant but on the content both objects.

One advantage of Constant.equals(variable) is that you can't have a NullPointerException on the .equals

Comment: NullPointerException  is very much known that's the reason my primarily focus is Performance.

Comment: @Frank: 1. Java is not an acrynom, so it's "Java", 2. Even if Performance is not great, performance considerations might still be interesting (difference between "bad" and "abysmal") and 3. Java is pretty good with performance these days, you're spreading FUD.

Comment: @Joachim Sauer 1. I write JAVA the way I want whether you have 76k or not, 2. Talking about Performance on a JVM running on a (assumption) DOS-NT-attachment (DOS& NT are acronyms) is fundamentally dense, 3. This is a QA Site and my last entry was an answer contrary to yours.

Answer (score 2):

If we compare **CONSTANT key(Left side of equals method)** with any **Object(Right side of equals method)** then compiler can do check comparison 
and give the expected result, but if we do vice versa **Object((Left side of equals method))** comparison with **Constant key((Right side of equals method))** then your program might through the **NULL POINTER EXCEPTION**.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String CONSTANT_KEY = "JAVA";
    String string = null;

    // CASE 1
    if (CONSTANT_KEY.equals(string)) {
        System.out.println("I am in if block");
    }

    // CASE 2   
    if (string.equals(string)) {
        System.out.println("I am in if block");
    }
}
```

**In above code case 1 is always safe to compare the objects to avoid NULL POINTER EXCEPTION instead of case 2.**

Answer (score 1):

Made a simple test with Strings:

```
final String constHello = "Hello";
final int times = 1000000000;

long constTimeStart = System.nanoTime();

for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
    constHello.equals("Hello");
}

long constTimeStop = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("constHello.equals(\"Hello\"); " + times + " times: " + (constTimeStop - constTimeStart) + " ns");


constTimeStart = System.nanoTime();

for (int i = 0; i < times; ++i) {
    "Hello".equals(constHello);
}

constTimeStop = System.nanoTime();

System.out.println("\"Hello\".equals(constHello); " + times + " times: " + (constTimeStop - constTimeStart) + " ns");
```

**Edit:**
As mentioned in the comments below, this wasn't a good way of doing micromeasurements. Switching which part of the code which was going to be executed first proved that warm up time played a significant role here. The first test always runs slower. Repeating the test multiple times in the same code to quickfix this makes the results more or less the same.

Comment: Note that you will always hit the fast-path in your comparison, since both objects are actually the same objects. Also, youre testing code is broken, because it does not take into account the warmup time.

Comment: See [this question on how to do correct microbenchmarks in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java).

Comment: @Joachim Sauer: You are right. Had an incomplete understanding of how to do these tests. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 1):

One good comparison can be:

```
private static String EXAMPLE = "Example";
private String obj = null;
```

case 1:

```
if(obj.equals(EXAMPLE) {
}
```

This is throw null pointer exception..

case 2 :

```
if(EXAMPLE.equals(obj)) {
}
```

This will not throw null pointer exception..

Answer (score 0):

I guess the code in `java.lang.String` supports my answer:

```
public boolean equals(Object anObject) {
    if (this == anObject) {
        return true;
    }
    if (anObject instanceof String) {
        String anotherString = (String)anObject;
        int n = count;
        if (n == anotherString.count) {
            char v1[] = value;
            char v2[] = anotherString.value;
            int i = offset;
            int j = anotherString.offset;
            while (n-- != 0) {
                if (v1[i++] != v2[j++])
                    return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: @tibo Can you please elaborate your last statement.

Comment: If it's not a string it means that its equal method is different and so maybe not symmetric

Answer (score 0):

- take this example : **object.equals(value)**

*if object is null than*

if(null.equals(value) {
}
This is throw null pointer exception..

if(value.equals(null)) {
}
This will not throw null pointer exception.. and do not entre the bloc

it is best to use the second chose if you don't know what this null object is.