# why String from intent cant use in "if clause"?

Tags: java, android, string, android-intent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

i have 2 class, let say a.class and b.class

and i want to send array from a to b using intent, in a.class

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,b.class);
intent.putExtra("stringtext", "1");
startActivity(intent);
```

and in b.class i catch the intent value with this

```
Intent it = getIntent();
String id = it.getStringExtra("stringtext");
```

when i try to print id, it give me "1"
but when i'm using id in if clause i didnt work, i try this

```
if(id=="1")
{
 teks.setText("its one");
}
else
{
 teks.setText("not one";
}
```

how could this happend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `equals()` method to compare string, `==` compares the reference for `Object`

Make it

```
if("1".equals(id))
{
  teks.setText("its one");
}
```

---

**See**

- [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)
- [Interview : Java Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712100/interview-java-equals/)