# If statement wont execute even though evaluation is true

Tags: java

In the following code, the block under `if(timesout[entry] == "exit")` will never execute. I have verified `timesout[entry]` for the current loop is set as "exit" in debugging mode, as well as by printing out the variable before the if statement is evaluated, but no matter what, the block never executes when I enter `exit` at the prompt, and I am stumped as to why.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class timetracker {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    boolean exit = false;
    String[] reasons = new String[30];
    String[] timesout = new String[30];
    String[] timesin = new String[30];
    int entry = 0;
    Scanner keyinput = new Scanner(System.in);

    recordloop:
    while(exit == false) {
        //record info



        System.out.println("Enter time out:");
        timesout[entry] = keyinput.nextLine();

        if(timesout[entry] == "exit") {
            exit = true;
            break recordloop;   
        }

        System.out.println("Enter reason:");
        reasons[entry] = keyinput.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Enter time in:");
        timesin[entry] = keyinput.nextLine();

        entry = entry + 1;

    }

    System.out.println("Times away from phone:\n ----- \n");
    int count = entry;
    entry = entry + 1;

    while(count < entry) {
        System.out.println(reasons[count] + ": " + timesout[count] + " - " + timesin[count] + "\n");
        count = count + 1;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: for string always use .equals() to compare.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: The [Java tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) has a small collection of common issues.  Comparing strings is one of many common issues that Java programmers come across.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
timesout[entry] == "exit"
```

use `equals()` to compare String, `==` compares reference equality

**See**

- [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)
- [Interview : Java Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712100/interview-java-equals/5712112#5712112)

Comment: Wow.  I'm a c# programmer so I'd have struggled with this too.  So does this imply that java doesn't use immutable strings?  Don't worry, I'll google it ;-)

Comment: java does, but it doesn't cache all the String in pool, so its better to use equals() to compare the Object equality

Comment: Ah yes, a quick google search revealed that too, thanks.  It's strange that comparing a string variable against a string literal doesn't cause a compiler warning, then?  I mean, it's perfectly clear what the programmer is trying to do (and I can't think of a scenario where I'd want to check if my variable references the same string that was created for me in "the back end" to represent my literal).

Comment: Thank you! I'm a PHP Programmer by nature so I wasn't sure what was going on here.

Comment: String caches instance in literal pool, where you could simply compare to see if they are equal then both of the Object are same and hence equals

Answer (score 4):

Instead of

```
if(timesout[entry] == "exit")
```

use

```
if(timesout[entry].equals("exit"))
```

or

```
if("exit".equals(timesout[entry]))
```

more information different between == and equals()

```
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12171783/how-is-it-possible-for-two-string-objects-with-identical-values-not-to-be-equal/12171818#12171818
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try

```
if("exit".equals(timesout[entry]))
```

instead of

```
if(timesout[entry] == "exit")
```

As `@Jigar Joshi` pointed you should [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) the difference and meaning of `==` and `equals()`