# Check if String equals class name

Tags: java

In my main method, my first argument is a class PersonInfo lets say. How do I do this?

```
 if(argument.equals(PersonInfo) {
  //invoke method A
 }

  if(argument.equals(MyInfo) {
  //invoke method B
 }
```

Since arguments in main method are Strings, how do I check if these Strings equal my class name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`PersonInfo.class.getSimpleName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSimpleName%28%29) is what you are looking for, and d[o it otherway so that you won't have to handle `null` check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712100/interview-java-equals/5712112#5712112)

Comment: Perfect. However, what happens when I do it the other way, and the argument the user passes is null? Do I need to do a null check there?

Comment: This answers it  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712100/interview-java-equals/5712112#5712112

Answer (score 1):

You want to get the name of the class then compare it to your `argument`.

```
if(argument.equals(PersonInfo.class.getSimpleName()))
{
  //invoke method A
}

if(argument.equals(MyInfo.class.getSimpleName()))
{
  //invoke method B
}
```