# Enabling a jbutton at startup

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I have a login form and a mainform.
In the mainform I have a disabled `JButton`.
I want to enable that `JButton` only if the username that I get from the login form is "admin".
I have a singleton controller instantiated in both forms.
I do something like

```
if(controller.admin=="admin"){jbutton.setEnabled(true)};
```

but I’m new to swing and I don't know where to use  this code. 
I tried using it in the mainform's constructor but it didn't work.

Comment: What about `MainForm_Load`

Comment: the load is called in the contructor. i did it. :D  all i had to do was to put my if statement after the initComponents() function.    private MainApp() {
      
        initComponents();
if(controller.admin.equalsIgnoreCase("admin")){
    this.jButton5.setEnabled(true);
}
    }

Comment: Did you try a windows listener to check when the form is actually loading up

Comment: *"I have a login form and a mainform"*  1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). 2) See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)  This sounds very familiar..

Comment: Don't use "==" for String comparisons. Instead you should be using the equals(...) method. For example: `"admin".equals(controller.admin)`. It is always a good idea to use the constant value first so you don't have to worry about null values in the controller.admin String.

Comment: As a complement for @camickr's comment (I didn't knew this) here's a link on why he said it: [Interview Java Equals](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712100/interview-java-equals)

Answer (score 2):

```
   if((controller.admin).equals("admin"))
  {
 jbutton.setEnabled(true);
  }
```

this is the correct code .please describe the questions with code