# Difference between using variable first and using variable at the end when comparing object?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null, equals

I have seen in many places that the constant value is used first and then the variable for example **("ram").equals(a)** and in many places I have seen that the variable is used first and then the constant value with which they want to compare for example **a.equals("ram")**.

what is the difference between a.equals("ram") and ("ram").equals(a) ?
which one is better to use and why ?

Comment: `"ram".equals(a)` (not sure why you have parenthesis) is "better" in that it won't throw an NPE is `a` is `null`.

Comment: This question has been asked over and over again (for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712100/interview-java-equals)). Please research first.

Comment: a.equals("ram") can throw a NullPointerException.

Comment: It’s *very* opinion-based. I happen to have a strong one: If you know `a` may be `null`, use `a != null && a.equals("ram")` to tell the reader that. If you know it cannot, use `a.equals("ram")` to tell the reader that. You are writing code for someone to read it and maintain it.

Answer (score 3):

The first style is safer in situations when variable `a` is allowed to be `null`, because you can skip `null` checking.

When you write

```
if (a.equals("ram")) { ... }
```

you must ensure that `a` is not `null` to avoid a null pointer exception. This is not necessary for

```
if ("ram".equals(a)) { ... }
```

because `equals()` method is required to process `null` arguments without throwing an exception:

> For any non-null reference value `x`, `x.equals(null)` should return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

("ram").equals(a) is better. The code will never break even if a is null.
saves us from null pointer exception.

Comment: But it will also hide an exception that should be thrown if a is not supposed to be null.

Comment: It also reads unnaturally, which impedes maintenance. The premise that it is better to avoid the `null` check is not obviously true, and respondents here have given engineering reasons why it's false. Otherwise the arguments in favor of the backwards idiom are based on emotion, not logic. I won't endorse either form in this comment, only plead that we base our decision on logic.